# Can someone explain Woodall's Conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand this:

http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/op/woodalls_conjecture

But, I am struggling with the definition. Any  explanation of "$ k $ disjoint dijoins" for laymen be great. I am totally clueless about this part (definition of disjoin too)..

Comment: Try modeling some Dijon’s on very small graphs.  It looks to me like you need to play around with some simple examples to get the hang of the definitions.

Comment: thank you.. can you recommend a book on GT that has it in detail.. the ones that I do they contain nothing on this..

"A dijoin is a set of edges which intersect every directed cut."

Its very unclear. Is disjoin the set of edges in each directed cut? Or is it the union of all edges present in each directed cut? If the case is latter, then "K disjoint disjoins" has no meaning.. The phrasing is so unclear..

Comment: it seems completely clear to me: a dijoin is a set of edges that is contained in every directed cut.  Presumably cuts have to be nonempty.

Comment: The definition seem perfectly clear but I can understand if you have no feeling for them: I don’t either. So, I would make progress by looking at small examples. For example, just look at two nodes with a directed edge between. There is only one cut and therefore that cut is also the only dijoin.

Comment: It seems to me the intersection of all directed cuts is the largest dijoin, and probably special.  I guess that doesn’t jive with what I conjectured about cuts being nonempty though. Maybe we should let dijoins be empty.

Comment: Great question. A directed cut is a set of arcs, and so is a dijoin. A set of arcs is a dijoin if it intersects the arcs in each directed cut. Equivalently, it is a set of arcs whose contraction yields a strongly connected digraph.